# PySpark 1.6.2 | collect() after orderBy/sort

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I don't understand the behaviour of this simple PySpark code snippet :

```
# Create simple test dataframe
l = [('Alice', 1),('Pierre', 3),('Jack', 5), ('Paul', 2)]
df_test = sqlcontext.createDataFrame(l, ['name', 'age'])

# Perform filter then Take 2 oldest
df_test = df_test.sort('age', ascending=False)\
             .filter('age < 4') \
             .limit(2)


df_test.show(2)
# This outputs as expected :
# +------+---+
# |  name|age|
# +------+---+
# |Pierre|  3|
# |  Paul|  2|
# +------+---+

df_test.collect()
# This outputs unexpectedly :
# [Row(name=u'Pierre', age=3), Row(name=u'Alice', age=1)]
```

Is this an expected behaviour of the collect() function ? How can I retrieve my column as a list that keeps the right order ?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't post the code that you actually ran. I just ran the code you posted and got the expected result, `[Row(name=u'Pierre', age=3), Row(name=u'Paul', age=2)]`

Comment: I just ran it 10 sec ago line after line in a PySpark shell (just forgot to add `sqlcontext = HiveContext(sc)` at the beginning) and got the same result. Could something be wrong with my spark installation ?

Comment: do `filter` before `sort`ing since that will eliminate sorting unnecessary rows and instead of `sort` , try `orderBy`

Comment: What Spark version are you running?

Comment: @Pushkr It works fine on this example with what you suggest. Thanks. However this is still quite disturbing !

Comment: @Tim P I am using Spark 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a sorter UDF to resolve this issue

```
def sorter(l):
    import operator
    res = sorted(l, key =operator.itemgetter(0))
    L1=[item[1] for item in res]
    #return " ".join(str(x) for x in L)
    return "".join(L1)

sort_udf = udf(sorter)
```